# Should I not do module.exports = foo(){} for easier testing

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, sinon

Sometimes I need a module to do just one thing.

Like, I have a `auth middleware` and *its job is to verify that user is authenticated.*

I don't think any reason there to do follow. 
*But here I can stub it easily using sinon*

```
const auth = asyn function(req, res, nex) {

}
module.exports = {
   auth: auth
}

//stubbing(in test.js)
const authStub = sinon.stub(authMiddleware, 'auth')
```

Instead I like to do

```
module.exports = async function(req, res, next) {

}
```

What's the problem with my approach?

One problem that I have faced. I can't stub `auth middleware` if I do `module.exprts = function(){}`

In this case I have to use some other libraries like `proxyquire` just to stub these type of `middlewares`.

What do you guys suggest?

Any alternative to achieve the same? 
Or It's better to not stub `auth` at all?

*I am only asking it for the testing point of view as a best practice. I know What's `moduel.exports` or `exports` does, also the difference.*